# sales_order_save_commit_after event triggered twice?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, event-observer

I registered an observer for the `sales_order_save_commit_after` event to be notified when a new order comes in. This works fine but the event is triggered two times in a row with the same order.

My config.xml

```
        <sales_order_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <unique_sales_order_save_commit_after>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                    <method>export</method>
                </unique_sales_order_save_commit_after>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_commit_after>
```

How can I check if it's the first time or which other event would be better?

**Update**

I also tried the `sales_order_invoice_pay` event (found on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927618/magento-observer-for-order-state-is-complete)) but that is not triggered for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `sales_order_save_after` instead, it's triggered right after an order is saved in the database and returns the full order object

Why this event is triggered twice, I'm not sure. It's an an event triggered from `Core/Model/Abstract.php` method `afterCommitCallback`, seems that Magento is saving / committing 2 different data sets on the the Order model. Perhaps once the order itself and once the status history.

Is there any difference between the data being parsed on the 2 events that might give a clue to where it's called from?

Comment: Thank you `sales_order_save_after` works but I will use `sales_order_place_after` as it is not triggered again by back end changes.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone is still having problem with this, I found out how magento deals with this.

In the called method you can take the order and set a flag on it.

Ex:

```
public function export(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    if($order->getExportProcessed()){ //check if flag is already set.
        return;
    }

    // your part of code

    //"setExportProcessed" can be called anything you want as it's getting set magically by magento on our $order object.
    $order->setExportProcessed(true); 
}
```

In app/code/core/Mage/Cataloginventory/Model/Observer.php

function subtractQuoteInventory(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)

is an example of how magento deals with this.

Answer (score 6):

I changed the event to `sales_order_place_after`. This works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function sendEmail(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    if(!Mage::registry('varien_event')){

        //your code here...

        Mage::register('varien_event',true);

    }
}
```

The Bove code is working for me.