# Dynamic event in Magento 2

Tags: event-observer, magento2

I working with dynamic event in Magento 2, i detected dynamic event call 3 times(example: `customer_address_save_after` event). This problem in here because i only want run once times this dynamic event.

How to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of flags you can use `Registry` class.

create instance from constructor

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    }
```

to register

```
$this->_coreRegistry->register('customer_address_save_observer_executed_' . $customerAddress->getId(),true);
```

to get the from register weather it's executed or not? if executed just return this otherwise it will execute.

```
if($this->_coreRegistry->registry('customer_address_save_observer_executed_' . $customerAddress->getId()))
                    return $this;
```

Comment: I try again but it not working

Comment: @Bill, post your code.

Comment: I create registry as you but it still run 3 times

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set a flag and check it before running your code.

```
if($flag) { //check if flag is already set
    return; // return, flag is set
} else {
    fn(); //your code here
    $flag = true;
}
```

Flag can be a session flag or something you add to the original object and check after.

Something (pretty) similar can be found [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7730/sales-order-save-commit-after-event-triggered-twice).

Comment: When declare $flag first times, Where i can get value to avoid undefined variable ?